# Callback NodeJS & insert data with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, asynccallback

I know this topic as already asked many times before but I didn't find the right answer to do what I want.

Actually, I try to save two different list of JSON object in MongoDB via Mongoose. To perform both at the same time I use *'async'*.
However, when I save it with the command *insertMany()* I get an error because he calls the callback of async before finishing the insertMany(). Therefore answer[0] is not defined.

What will be the proper way of doing it ?

Here is my code with the async:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const async = require("async");
const utils = require("../utils");

const experimentCreate = function(req, res) {
  let resData = {};
  let experimentList = req.body.experiment;
  let datasetList = req.body.datasetList;

  async.parallel(
        {
          dataset: function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              answer = utils.createDataset(datasetList);
              callback(answer[0], answer[1]);
            }, 100);
          },
          experiment: function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              answer = utils.createExp(experimentList);
              callback(answer[0], answer[1]);
            }, 100);
          }
        },
        function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error dataset or metadata creation: " + err);
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
          } else {
            console.log("Experiment created.");
            resData.push(result.dataset);
            resData.push(result.experiment);
            console.log(resData);
            sendJSONresponse(res, 200, resData);
          }
        }
      );
};
```

Then the two functions called createExp and createDataset are the same in another file. Like this:

```
const createDataset = function(list) {
  let datasetList = [];
  for (item of list) {
    let temp = {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: item.name,
      description: item.description,
      type: item.type,
    };
    datasetList.push(temp);
  }

  Dataset.insertMany(datasetList, (err, ds) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error dataset creation: " + err);
      return [err, null];
    } else {
      console.log("All dataset created.");
      return [null, ds];
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code. For one, you're not returning anything in your `createDataset` function. You're returning a value in the callback of `insertMany` but it doesn't return that value to the caller of `createDataset` as it's within another scope. To solve this issue, you can wrap your `Dataset.insertMany` in a promise, and resolve or reject depending on the result of `Data.insertMany` like this:

```
const createDataset = function(list) {
  let datasetList = [];
  for (item of list) {
    let temp = {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: item.name,
      description: item.description,
      type: item.type,
    };
    datasetList.push(temp);
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Dataset.insertMany(datasetList, (err, ds) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error dataset creation: " + err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log("All dataset created.");
        resolve(ds);
      }
    });
  });   
};
```

Now your return object is no longer going to be an array so you won't be able to access both the error and the result via `answer[0]` and `answer[1]`. You're going to need to chain a `then` call after you call `createDataset` and use `callback(null, answer)` in the `then` call (as that means `createDataset` executed successfully) or use `callback(err)` if `createDataset` throws an error like below:

```
dataset: function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    utils.createDataset(datasetList).then(answer => {
      callback(null, answer);
    }).catch(err => callback(err)); // handle error here);
  }, 100);
}
```

**Note:** You'll most likely need to alter your `createExp` code to be structurally similar to what I've produced above if it's also utilizing asynchronous functions.